# embed zippyshare player into a local html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I try to embed this zippyshare player

```
<script type="text/javascript">var zippywww="54";var zippyfile="JnIxIFUy";var zippytext="#000000";var zippyback="#e8e8e8";var zippyplay="#ff6600";var zippywidth=850;var zippyauto=false;var zippyvol=80;var zippywave = "#000000";var zippyborder = "#cccccc";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js"></script>
```

into a html file on my pc! When I do this and open it, it will show nothing!

Any idea to do this or why it don't work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In Chrome or IE, look at the console (F12 in IE, Right-Click - Inspect) and refresh. See what the console is showing and provide any errors that are showing up.

Comment: on firebug I only see one error "304 Not Modified"! is that reasonable for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but kind of interesting since their embed code didn't work out-of-the-box for me either.

Here's how I managed to embed the Zippyshare player into my html for anyone facing this same issue.

If you look at the embed code, there is this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js"></script>` at the end of all the declared parameters. Copy that url `http://api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js` into your browser and there's the iframe you are looking for... right?

This is what it looks like:

```
var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;
document.write("<iframe height=\"92\" width=\""+zippywidth+"\" frameBorder=\"0\" src=\""+window.location.protocol+"//api.zippyshare.com/api/jplayer_embed.jsp?key="+zippyfile+"&server=www"+zippywww+"&width="+zippywidth+"\"></iframe>");
```

Somehow, however, your webpage never receives this. So I copied that part and pasted into my html code, replacing the zippyshare script call and modifying it a bit (replacing escape characters with single quotes). So my html now looks like this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var zippywww="20";
    var zippyfile="CyeL81Cn";
    var zippytext="#000000";
    var zippyback="#e8e8e8";
    var zippyplay="#ff6600";
    var zippywidth="100%";
    var zippyauto=false;
    var zippyvol=80;
    var zippywave = "#000000";
    var zippyborder = "#cccccc";

    var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;        
    document.write("<iframe height='92' width='"+zippywidth+"' frameBorder='0' src='http://api.zippyshare.com/api/jplayer_embed.jsp?key="+zippyfile+"&server=www"+zippywww+"&width="+zippywidth+"' allowfullscreen></iframe>");

    </script>   
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="//api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js"></script-->

</body>
```

It works, **BUT** I still wouldn't recommend it as it defeats the core purpose of having an api call. So this is not as much an answer as it is a very temporary fix :) while you figure it out or while Zippyshare figures out what to do with all those unused customization parameters you specify.